# Error in WDK while compile using x64 checked build environment

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, wdk

I try to build a kernel mode driver in windows 7 x64.I already disable the patch guard.whenever i open the x64 checked build environment command prompt i get this error
"WARNING: x64 Native compiling isn't supported. Using cross compilers".Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an error.  It's perfectly normal and you can ignore it.  It's just telling you that the x64 compiler is actually a 32-bit compiler that generates 64-bit code.  Hence the term "cross compilers."

Comment: I am getting 2 more errors while i run in x64 checked environment                           like error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol_imp_KeServiceDescriptorTable how to solve this error.but when i run in ia64 environment i did not get this error !!!1